# Why can't execute the cmd on background on win10?

Tags: windows-10, background

Some app was started by the command :

```
c:\client_windows_amd64.exe -c c:\config.json
```

It works fine in window's cmd,now i want it run on win10's background.

```
start \B  "c:\client_windows_amd64.exe -c c:\config.json"
```

It encountered no error , but  the some app can't work ,what is matter with the start command?

Answer (score 2):

#### What is the matter with the start command?

> ```
> start \B  "c:\client_windows_amd64.exe -c c:\config.json"
> ```

You are using it incorrectly.

1. The `\B` should be `/B`.
2. The parameters are not meant to be part of the command string.
3. You are missing a window title (`start` is interpreting `"c:\client_windows_amd64.exe -c c:\config.json"` as the windows title as it is the first quoted string):

   > Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes ""
   >
   > According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Try the following command:

```
start "MyTitle" /b "c:\client_windows_amd64.exe" -c c:\config.json
```

Source [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)